# Hiding and showing another div with same child class breaks script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a login form with a link to a Forgot password, when this is clicked the login div hides using fadeOut() and then the Forgot Password div is shown using fadeIn().

But when I hade a child element to the Forgot password with the same class as in the div that's getting hidden the Forgot password doesn't show up at all.

Function that hides login and displays forgot password

```js
function forgotPassword() {
  $('.login, .register, .or').fadeOut(500).promise().then(function() {
    $('.forgotpassword').fadeIn(500);
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box account login">
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Login</h3>

    <div id="errorLogin">
      <p id="errorLoginMsg"></p>
    </div>

    <label for="email2">
      Email
      <input name="email2" id="email2" placeholder="Email...">
    </label>
    <label for="pw3">
      Password
      <input name="pw3" id="pw3" type="password" placeholder="Password...">
    </label>

    <button id="submitLogin" disabled="true">Login</button>
    <a id="forgotPassword_btn" onClick="forgotPassword()">Forgot password? Click here</a>
  </div>

  <div class="bg blue"></div>
</div>

<div class="box account forgotpassword" style="display:none;">
  <div class="content">//Adding this class breaks the script
    <p>Forgot password</p>
  </div>

  <div class="bg blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code appears to work fine - as you can see from the snippet I added to your question. Check the console for errors in your working code. I would assume there is another block of code, or even CSS if it's a layout issue, which is interfering with the intended behaviour

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  It works here but not on the real site, if I remove the class "content" it displays like it should. It seems like because I hide a div with the child class I can't display that child class again even if I add that child class to the fadeIn().

The script doesn't "break" (bad wording on my part) but it never displays the "forgot password"-DIV because of the "content"-class.

Comment: In that case it definitely sounds like a CSS issue. Check the element in the DOM inspector to see which styles are applied with the `.content` class

Comment: Turned out to be the CSS, thank you so much for your help! @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1):

Just change the place of **style="display:none"** to child div means it should be like this

```
<div class="box account forgotpassword"><div class="content" style="display:none;">//Adding this class breaks the script
<p>Forgot password</p></div><div class="bg blue"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of search it turned out to be the CSS which for some reason didn't give a full height to the div that was going to be displayed.

I'd like to add that you shouldn't use onClick="", instead you should use an eventListener or if you can use jQuery's .click() function.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a `callback` function to `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` functions. Link [here](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).

For example:

```js
function forgotPassword() {
    // fadeOut with callback
    $('.login').fadeOut(500, function(){
        // then...
        $('.forgotpassword').fadeIn(500);
    });
};
```